why i can not deploy python web app easily?
why I can not deploy the Python web application and put it in a folder like the WWW folder of the Apache server so I can access it immediately?
like any server-side programming language like PHP?
always I have to find a VPS service, of a Cloud computer to be accessed as root, put my files then run the server of python with another server like Nginx or Apache and I have to do a lot of configuration,
why it is not like PHP I can through it in the folder of the server and install PHP and this is everything?

why it is not like PHP Because PHP was designed to be that way, and Python wasn't.

@JohnGordon your answer is the greatest answer I have seen about this question, honestly, I was thinking for a long time and why and how I make it work like that, and you convinced me ... but I am asking why it is not like that, what is the difference in the design, that makes PHP as easy as that while python you have to create a perfect environment for it to work ..... I am asking about the difference in the design that prevents this from happening.  also, thanks for your answer.

Short answer:
Quite simply, Python is not designed to run like that.
Longer answer:
The biggest difference between Python and PHP, in this context, is how they're run. PHP is a language designed to run websites. When you make a request to a web service that uses PHP, you make a request to a specific file which is served using the PHP server software. One piece of server software can run any PHP code, so when purchasing shared hosting plans (where you don't have root or CLI access and can't run your own software), it's often super easy for them to deploy PHP.
Python, on the other hand, isn't primarily a website language. In fact, when you make a website using Python, you're coding the server yourself. You have a much lower-level access to your server's OS and can do virtually anything, so in practice you can't really run Python on a shared hosting plan.
So the difference from a hosting standpoint is the level of access they give you. When using Python, you need a VPS because you are creating your own software for the server to run. PHP, on the other hand, is just uploaded by you and the hosting provider takes care of the rest. They fundamentally take different strategies to run and host.
So, you can typically host PHP from either a shared host or a VPS, but Python you typically can only run on a VPS.
This is a very high-level general answer, but hope it helps!
